# How to save results into new dataframe after applying conditions in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have my IDs identified with the following line:

```
inactiveOne =  df['id'].loc[(df['Button'] == '-') & (df['True/False'] == 'TRUE') & (df['status'] == 'OK')]
```

How could I save my IDs as a new column in new dataframe?

When I do the following, it creates a file but I have all rows truncated into one cell, instead of having hundreds of rows with my IDs.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={"id": [inactiveOne]})
df2.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the extra brackets around `inactiveOne`, just do:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={"id": inactiveOne})
df2.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

pandas.loc as you have written it will return a series object which supports `to_csv()` method. No need to create another dataframe object first. You can simply do

```py
inactiveOne =  df['id'].loc[(df['Button'] == '-') & (df['True/False'] == 'TRUE') & (df['status'] == 'OK')]
inactiveOne.to_csv('test.csv',index=False)
```